# reCAPTCHA 2.0 challenge type

Tags: recaptcha

Does anyone know if is possible to choose the type of challenge that the new recaptcha will prompt to the user?

For instance in professional looking website the challenge "select the steak below" with a pool of images with steaks in it is not really good

I went through the docs but there is not such thing
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#config

any idea?

Thanks